# How to Initialize Interface In Flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I'm new to Flex. I have some doubt regarding Interface in Flex. As we know AS3 is also an Object Oriented Language.
Questions are :

1.if class A extends Class B. Then Class A can't implements interface C. Why ?

1. The class which don't extends other class can implement the interface. What is the reason behind that ?
2. why we can't give access specifier to the functions declaration in Flex Interface ?

   Why can't we write like 
   class A extends class B implements C

Updates Of My Question with Code

Interface Part ->

```
package
{
    public interface InterfaceTesting
    {
        function foo():void;        
    }

}
```

Class A ->

```
package
{
    import mx.controls.Alert;

    public class A 
    {
        public function test():void
        {
            trace("control is in Top Class")
            Alert.show("control is in Top Class");
        }   

    }

}
```

Class B ->

```
package
{
    import mx.controls.Alert;
    import mx.messaging.channels.StreamingAMFChannel;
    import mx.states.OverrideBase;

    public class B extends A implements InterfaceTesting
    {
        override public function test():void
        {
            Alert.show("We are in Second Class");
        }

      public function foo():void
        {
            Alert.show("This is Interface Implementation");
        }
}
}
```

I'm getting an Error in class B. which is 1024- Overriding a function which is not marked for override.

Please Guide me.

Comment: `Why can't we write like class A extends class B implements C` > yes you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but what you're describing should be possible.

A valid example:

**ClassA.as**

```
package  {
    public class ClassA extends ClassB implements InterfaceC {
        public function ClassA() {

        }

        public function bar():void {

        }
    }
}
```

**ClassB.as**

```
package  {
    public class ClassB {

        public function ClassB() {

        }

        public function foo():void {

        }
    }
}
```

**InterfaceC.as**

```
package {
    public interface InterfaceC {
        function foo():void; // Will be inherited from ClassB 
        function bar():void; // Is defined in ClassA
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Regarding your third question:

To comply with an interface, the methods defined in the interface needs to be either `public` or `internal`. This is because an interface is useful only for declaring what methods are available publicly.

If your class implements `InterfaceC` (above) and contains the function `foo()` but has declared it private - it cannot be reached externally and hence won't comply with the interface.

Comment: If i have to show overriding in class A  and i'm trying to implement interface C also.
Would it work same. Because i was using overriding in class A and implementing interface also.
It was giving me Error.

Comment: @AnujSharma Overriding should be fine. For instance, if I override `foo()` (which is defined in `ClassB`) in `ClassA` by writing `public override function foo():void`, everything compiles as it should since the class is still exposing the `foo` method as defined in the interface. Please update your question with the error you got and the structure of the classes you have problems with.